# In MVC, what does the model do and what is the relation with SwingWorker?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, swingworker

I read a lot about Java, Swing, MVC and SwingWorker but I'm totally confused about the role of the Model in MVC.

I'm building an app that has two buttons:

1. select file
2. read file

There is also a textbox used for logging.

What I'm currently doing:

1. The View contains the widgets but no logic
2. The button's actionPerformed() methods call a method on the Controller
3. The Controller will fetch required data (incl. displaying an OptionPane.showOpenDialog()) for getting the File
4. File reference is stored in the Model.
5. Model notifies (PropertyChangeSupport, Observer pattern) the View of the new File.
6. View enables the 'read file' button

**My first question**: should I store the state in the Model? That is, information related to the sequence of operation: first a file must be selected before it can be read. So then my Model would become a state machine.

**My second question**: is it correct that I let the Controller show the OptionPane?

Then the fun starts. The user clicks the 'read file' button. I'm doing more or less the same as with the 'select file' button. The View calls the Controller, but the Controller uses a SwingWorker to read the file since this should not be done on the EDT. The SwingWorker publishes intermediate logging messages that are added to the textbox via a reference to the View (SwingWorker.process() method). The Controller listens for 'state' property changes from the SwingWorker. When the 'state' is 'DONE' then the Controller calls the 'get()' function. If everything is OK, the results are set in the Model. If not, exceptions are handled.

**My third and most important question**: shouldn't the Model do the file reading?! The whole point of MVC is separation of concerns, with all the benefits (testability etc.). What if I wanted a new View (e.g. CLI)? Then my Model would now only be a Data Model. It doesn't have a clue about how to read the file! And what about the threading issues?

Hopefully you can give me some good advice. There are tons of examples on the Internet about SwingWorker, MVC etc. But my problem is not on how to code against them, but how to design.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're pretty much on track. To answer your questions one by one:

**1. should I store the state in the Model?** 
yes, you can and should store state in your model - the model is state and behavior that alters that state.

**2. is it correct that I let the Controller show the OptionPane?**
yes - the application design (logic flow) decides where the file comes from - the model certainly doesn't care how the file name to read is obtained, just that it gets a filename. flow is the domain of the controller.

**3. shouldn't the Model do the file reading?**
yes again, file reading is part of the model. Even though the controller is invoking the swing worker, the swing worker is conceptually part of the model, at least the primary logic executed by the swing worker. Ideally, all the logic to load the file lives in model classes. The controller can then arrange for this to be called using a swing worker. The controller is who decides that the file loading should happen on a background thread, and instructs the model to load the file from the background. The controller's swing worker receives the loading progress events from the model and handles these by calling publish(), and then process() updates the UI.

In principle, you should be able to rewrite the entire app as a console app without needing to change the model. Naturally, the view changes, but it's because it now has to present the model using stdout rather than Swing. The biggest changes happen in the controller - application flow would be different (file selection comes from program arguments), controller no longer listens to button clicks to direct flow but either has a fixed flow, or interacts with the user via stdin. And the threading model in the controller is different - no need to worry about the EDT, so no need for swing worker.

So you see, the model takes care of state and changes to that state, the view takes care of presenting the state, and the controller does everything else, in particular connecting the model to the view.

Comment: One of the best succinct posts I've seen on MVC and Swing -- thanks!